# SQL Server - Linked Server to Progress via ODBC

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, linked-server, progress-4gl

I want to link a Progress DB to MS SQL Server. I use the guide on:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P120484

Local on my Windows 8 notebook, I have also installed a MS SQL Management Studio.

"1) Setup an ODBC connection to the Progress eatabase in the ODBC Administrator in the System DSN. Make sure the connection successfully establishes."

So I looked under System-DNS and find it. It is called pA52_T2_ODBC. 32-Bit. Progress OpenEdge 10.2B Driver. When I test the connection, it says "Connection established!". So I think step 1 is done.

"2) Bring up SQL Server Management Studio, connect to Object Explorer. Under Server Objects -> Linked Servers, Right click -> New Linked Server.
3) Provide the information to following options:

Linked server - Provide the name you will use to refer to this linked server.
Server Type - Select "Other data source" as server type. Clicking this option activates the options below it.
Provider -  Microsoft OLE DB provider for ODBC driver.
Product name - it could be anything but better to use progress since it is a progress database.
Data source - ODBC System DSN name. The rest of the options can be left blank".

And now it doesn't work! I get an Error-Msg: The linked server has been updated but failed a connection test... Error: 7303.

Why works the connection test in step 1, but not with step 2?

Any ideas?

UPDATE 1:

Now I tried to import a table from progress to MS Access. I use the pA52_T2_ODBC, type in my loginname and password. Then a window opens and I can chooese all the progress tables. But when I choose one and click ok then I get this error:

[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Access denied (Authorization failed) (7512)(#-20228).

Why can I pass first with my login data, but in second step it failed about this!?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to stem from the fact that you don't have any tables granted to your SQL login. The `Access denied (Authorization failed)` message refers to your query on the table, not your login to the database.

If you are following the Knowledgebase guide, you'll have to use `sqlexp` or equivalent to run `GRANT` scripts against the Progress table(s) you want to query for the SQL login(s) you are using.

For example:

`GRANT SELECT ON PUB.YourTable TO YourUser;
COMMIT;`